# An error occurred: IntegrationError: Missing value for stripe.confirmCardPayment intent secret: value should be a client_secret string

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, stripe-payments

I have a React app on the frontend, and a django rest API on the back.

I'm trying to get Payment Request Button to work with Apple and Google Pay.

When I test it on the frontend, I get the following message in the browser console:

`An error occurred: IntegrationError: Missing value for stripe.confirmCardPayment intent secret: value should be a client_secret string.`

I believe there is an issue in my views.py which contains the following:

## views.py

```
class PaymentIntentView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        amount = request.data.get('amount')
        currency = request.data.get('currency')
        automatic_payment_methods = request.data.get('automatic_payment_methods')

        try:
            intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
                amount=amount,
                currency=currency,
                automatic_payment_methods={
                    'enabled': True,
                },
                # You can also add other options like capture_method, setup_future_usage, etc.
            )

            return Response({'client_secret': intent.client_secret, 'id': intent.id})
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({'error': str(e)})
```

## Checkout.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  PaymentRequestButtonElement,
  useStripe,
} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import axios from 'axios';

const Checkout = (props) => {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const [paymentRequest, setPaymentRequest] = useState(null);
  const price = props.price;
  const dollar_price = price * 100;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (stripe) {
      const pr = stripe.paymentRequest({
        country: 'US',
        currency: 'usd',
        total: {
          label: 'Purchase',
          amount: dollar_price,
        },
        requestPayerName: true,
        requestPayerEmail: true,
        applePay: true,
        googlePay: true,
      });

      pr.canMakePayment().then(result => {
        if (result) {
          setPaymentRequest(pr);
        }
      });
    }
  }, [stripe]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (paymentRequest) {
      paymentRequest.on('paymentmethod', async event => {
        const paymentMethod = event.paymentMethod;
        try {
          const response = await axios.post(
            '/my/django/end-point/create-payment-intent',
            {
              paymentMethodId: paymentMethod.id,
              amount: price,
              automatic_payment_methods: {
                'enabled': true,
              },
              currency: 'usd',
            }
          );

          const pi = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(response.data.client_secret, {
            payment_method: paymentMethod.id
          });

          console.log(pi);
          if (pi.status === 'succeeded') {
            event.complete('success');
            console.log('Payment succeeded!');
            window.location.href = '/success';
          } else if (pi.status === 'requires_action' || pi.status === 'requires_confirmation') {
            event.complete('success');
            console.log('Additional steps required!');
            // Prompt user to complete additional steps
          } else if (pi.status === 'requires_payment_method') {
            event.complete('fail');
            console.log('Payment method required!');
            // Prompt user to add a new payment method
          } else if (pi.status === 'processing') {
            event.complete('success');
            console.log('Payment is being processed!');
            // Show a message to the user that the payment is being processed
          } else if (pi.status === 'canceled') {
            event.complete('fail');
            console.log('Payment canceled!');
            // Show a message to the user that the payment was canceled
          } else if (pi.status === 'failed') {
            event.complete('fail');
            console.log('Payment failed!');
            // Show a message to the user that the payment failed
          }
        } catch (error) {
          event.complete('fail');
          console.log('An error occurred:', error);
          // Show an error message to the user
        }
      });
    }
  }, [paymentRequest, stripe]);


  if (paymentRequest) {
    return <PaymentRequestButtonElement options={{ paymentRequest }} />;
  }

  return 'Insert your form or button component here.';
};

export default Checkout;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be following the recommended approach for the Payment Request Button using React specified [here](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button?client=react).  The first step in troubleshooting this would be to add some logging to your [Django back-end](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/logging/) to validate the `intent` is being created and returned as you expect.  You might even want to assign the `Response` to a variable and log that prior to returning it.

Then I would add a `console.log()` statement to check the `response` that is being returned by your `axios.post()` call.  You might try assigning the secret so you can log just that (e.g. `const secret = request.data.client_secret`).

The last thing I would check is whether the case for the variable is preserved between your front-end and back-end.  I'm not an expert on JS Frameworks but I've noticed I will use snake case for property names in my back-end (e.g. `nifty_stuff`) only to have that transformed to camel case in the front-end (e.g. `niftyStuff`).  Logging the `request.data` in your front-end should reveal if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Toload the stripe component some props are must.

you should pass, pk and amount

pk(clientSecret) should be a string value and amount should be a number containing cents make sure no decimal points.
stripe will assign decimal point and last two digits of the amount number should represent the cent value.